# How to create a random matrix using arrays

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I wanted to create a random 5x5 matrix using arrays and the Arrays.fill method.
This is what I did:

```
import java.util.*;

class RandomMatrix {
    public static void main (String  [] args) {

        int i,j;
        int [] [] matrix = new int [5] [5];
        Arrays.fill (matrix, (int) Math.random()*10);

        for (i=0; i<matrix.length; i++) {
            for (j=0; j<matrix[i].length; j++) {

                System.out.printf("%-5d", matrix [i][j]);
            }           
            System.out.println();
        }           
    }
}
```

I actually thought it would work this way but now i get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.lang.Integer
    at java.util.Arrays.fill(Unknown Source)
    at RandomMatrix.main(RandomMatrix.java:8)
```

Comment: Did you realize that you're not creating a 5x5 matrix with 25 randomly chosen elements, but a 5x5 matrix where all elements are equal (yet, randomly chosen)?

Comment: A 2D-array is an array of an array. So you have to fill `matrix` (which is an array of `int[]`) with `int[]`s, not `int`s. Hence the `ArrayStoreException`.

Comment: Math.random() > Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0. if is 0 <= 0.5 when you cast to integer this is equal to 0. and 0*10 =0 invalid array assign dimension

Answer (score 3):

Use the same loop structure that you use for printing the matrix.

```
for (int i=0; i<matrix.length; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<matrix[i].length; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = (int) (Math.random()*10);
    }           
}
```

`Arrays.fill()` works on arrays, your matrix is an array consisting of arrays. Even if you used something like  `Arrays.fill (matrix[0], (int) Math.random()*10);`, you would put the same (randomly chosen) value into each cell of row 0.

Comment: Thanks this worked out. But actually I wanted to try out the Arrays.fill method, as it was introduced today at university. So is there a way to get the same result with this method?

Comment: I don't think so. Any expression you use as parameter for ´fill(...)´ will be resolved before actually calling the method, so it uses the same value for each cell, that's what ´fill(...)´ is designed to do.

Comment: What you actually look for would be a fill method that supports both, recursive arrays and values provided by a Supplier. I don't think this exists, but if you happen to have this problem in more than one place, you might consider implementing it at least for a 2D case.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays.fill() fills an array. Your matrix is an array of arrays, so instead of writing

```
Arrays.fill (matrix, (int) Math.random()*10);
```

you could also write

```
int a = (int) Math.random()*10;
matrix[0] = a; //doesn't work, matrix[0] is an int array!
matrix[1] = a; //doesn't work, matrix[0] is an int array!
```

and so on. See why it doesn't work? It's wrong in two ways. First, fill() doesn't support nested arrays, and second, fill takes a value as parameter, not a supplier.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have got an error because method fill() can't work with the multi-dimensional array. Just convert it look like :

```
for(int k = 0;k<5;k++){
        int[] example = matrix[k];
        Arrays.fill (example, new Random().nextInt(10)*10);
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    int[][] m = new int[5][5];

    //https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill-int:A-int-
    //public static void fill(**int[]** a,  int val)
    for(int[] r : m)
        Arrays.fill(r, (int) (Math.random()*10));

    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(m[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    System.out.println("Second");

    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m.length; j++) {
            m[i][j] = (int) (Math.random()*10);
        }
    }       

    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(m[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
Output:
3 3 3 3 3 
4 4 4 4 4 
7 7 7 7 7 
2 2 2 2 2 
8 8 8 8 8 
Second
0 0 4 9 1 
5 8 6 3 8 
5 7 3 5 1 
1 1 6 4 8 
6 2 1 4 0
```